# Escape Double Quotes JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Trying to place a variable into the value field as shown below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="descrip" value="' + descrip + '" name="descrip[]">
```

However if working with a string such as 1" RT OFFSET with double quotes it places things into value as this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="descrip" value="1" rt offset" name="descrip[]">
```

Since this places value as `value="1"` it stops at the 1 and ignores the rest.

Thinking I would have to escape the double quotes I tried the below, but that only sets the value to `value="1\"` at that point so still cuts off at the " as in 1 inch.

```
descrip = descrip.replace(/(["])/g, "\\$1");
```

What am I missing here to set the value field of descrip properly when involving a double quote?

Comment: Your question doesn't even make sense.  What are you starting with (html) and what do you want it to end up looking like (html)?  Most likely you shouldn't be doing it with regex.  Your initial HTML is just completely invalid standing alone like that.

Comment: I need the final output to be 1" RT OFFSET.  The `+ descrip +` is being pulled from a MySQL call.  When that loads into the value of the input the double quote throws it off as `value="1" rt offset"` and then only POST will pick things up as `value="1"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
descrip = descrip.replace('"', '&quot;');
```

When you post it back to server, replace it again.

Comment: Thank you! So simple yet I overlooked it every time.